# Create Temporary Table with Select and Values

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, temp-tables

I'm trying to create a temporary table in Hive as follows:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE mydb.tmp2 
AS SELECT * FROM (VALUES (0, 'abc')) 
AS T (id , mystr);
```

But that gives me the following error:

```
SemanticException [Error 10296]: Values clause with table constructor not yet supported
```

Is there another way to create a temporary table by explicitly and directly providing the values in the same command?

My ultimate goal is to run a `MERGE` command, and the temporary table would be inserted after the `USING` command. So something like this:

```
MERGE INTO mydb.mytbl
USING <temporary table>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use subquery instead of temporary table:

```
MERGE INTO mydb.mytbl t
USING  (SELECT 0 as id, 'abc' as mystr) tmp on tmp.id = t.id
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm currently doing, but it only works if I first execute `USE mydb;`, and then the `MERGE` command. See this: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/178176/hive-creation-of-temp-tables-in-default-database-d.html

Answer (score 0):

Hive does not support `values` constructor yet. You can achieve this using below query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE mydb.tmp2 
AS SELECT 0 as id, 'abc' as mystr;
```

**For merge, you can use temporary table as below:**

```
merge into target_table
using ( select * from mydb.tmp2) temp
on temp.id = target_table.id
when matched then update set ...
when not matched then insert values (...);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. But how would that fit into the `MERGE INTO` command?

Comment: Thanks, but that requires two steps... I'm hoping to find a way to run the `MERGE` command in a single step. This is motivated by Hive defaulting to the "default" database, where I don't have permission to create a temporary table. See this: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/178176/hive-creation-of-temp-tables-in-default-database-d.html